# SmartGWT Isomorphic Datasource aggregate SQL functions

Tags: datasource, aggregate-functions, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I'm looking to get the maximum value of a column from an instance of a com.isomorphic.datasource.DataSource.  Is this possible?

A general "**run this sql against this datasource**" would be particularly helpful, as later I'll be looking to do more, including getting a row "count" for some criteria.

I *could technically* fetch ALL records and iterate through them myself, though this is clearly less than optimal.  I can't seem to find anything related in the SmartGWT docs.

I'm using:
SmartGWT Power v3.0.p20121127

Answer (score 0):

In DataSource, applyFilter() methods with different different arguments are there you can use one of them and using Criteria and AdvancedCriteria you can do.